# Why is this list index out of range

Tags: python

I've a python program which is crashing with error `list index out of range` on the following line of code:

```
        split_choices_translated = map(unicode.strip, [value for key, value in obj.items() if 'choice_set_' in key][0].split(';'))
```

These are the variables and values in use when this happens:

```
Variable    Value
item_id     u'usage'

item_type   u'radiobutton'

key         'definition'

obj         {'category': u'how_use_words',
 'choices__choice_set': u'not yet; sometimes; often',
 'definition': u'does your child ever talk about past events or people who are not present?',
 'itemID': u'item_681',
 'item_type': u'usage'}

object_group  <QuerySet [{'itemID': u'item_681', 'item_type': u'usage', 'choices__choice_set': u'not yet; sometimes; often', 'category': u'how_use_words', 'definition': u'does your child ever talk about past events or people who are not present?'}, {'itemID': u'item_682', 'item_type': u'usage', 'choices__choice_set': u'not yet; sometimes; often', 'category': u'how_use_words', 'definition': u"does your child ever talk about something that's going to happen in the future?"}, {'itemID': u'item_683', 'item_type': u'usage', 'choices__choice_set': u'not yet; sometimes; often', 'category': u'how_use_words', 'definition': u'does your child talk about objects that are not present?'}, {'itemID': u'item_684', 'item_type': u'usage', 'choices__choice_set': u'not yet; sometimes; often', 'category': u'how_use_words', 'definition': u'does your child understand if you ask for something that is not in the room?'}, {'itemID': u'item_685', 'item_type': u'usage', 'choices__choice_set': u'not yet; sometimes; often', 'category': u'how_use_words', 'definition': u'does your child ever pick up or point to an object and name an absent person to whom the object belongs?'}]>

prefilled_data   {}

raw_split_choices  [u'not yet', u'sometimes', u'often']

value   u'does your child ever talk about past events or people who are not present?'
```

I cannot workout what is going wrong

Comment: add what the list contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fails because the test in your conditional list comprehension:

```
if 'choice_set_' in key
```

is never `true` because none of the keys in your input have `choice_set_` as a substring.  Because of this, your comprehension returns an empty list, but then you try to address the first item in that list.  Since there is no first item, you get the `list index out of range` error.